# Por qué se renderiza antes de terminar el useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, usestate, nextjs

Me gustaría saber porque el componente se renderiza antes de que termine la ejecución de un useEffect el cual actualiza un estado.

Explico: tengo un componente que renderiza un listado de vídeos dependiendo de si hay una búsqueda o no.

```
const Masterclass = () => {
  const [sections, setSections] = useState<ISection[]>([]);
  const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState<IMasterclass>();
  const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [keyword, seyKeyword] = useState<string>("");
  const [searchedVideos, setSearchedVideos] = useState<IMasterclass[]>([]);

  let { t } = useTranslation();

  const handleSearchSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const value = e.target.search.value;
    setKeywords([...keywords, value]);
    seyKeyword("");
  };

  const handleKeywordChange = (e: any) => {
    seyKeyword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDeleteKeyword = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const keyword = e.target.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
    const new_keywords = keywords.filter((word) => word !== keyword);
    setKeywords(new_keywords);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialMasterclasses().then((res) => {
      const sectionsList = getSections(res);
      setSections(sectionsList);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedVideo) {
      searchMasterclasses("hola que tal");
      /*getMasterclassComments(selectedVideo.id).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });*/
    }
  }, [selectedVideo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let videos: IMasterclass[] = [];
    keywords.map((word) => {
      searchMasterclasses(word).then((res) => {
        res.map((video: IMasterclass) => {
          if (
            !videos.find((v) => {
              return v.id === video.id;
            })
          ) {
            videos.push(video);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(keywords, searchedVideos);
    setSearchedVideos(videos);
    console.log(videos, searchedVideos);
  }, [keywords]);

  return (
    <>
      <Head />
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1>{t("masterclass:title")}</h1>

        {/** ===> VIDEO PLAYER SECTION <===*/}
        {selectedVideo !== undefined ? (
          
          <VideoPlayerSection_copy
            videos={sections.find(section => section.name === selectedVideo.section.name)?.videos}
            currentVideo={selectedVideo}
          />
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        {/** ===> END VIDEO PLAYER SECTION <===*/}

        {/** ===> SEARCH BAR <===*/}
        <div className={styles.search_input_container}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit}>
            <InputSingleLine
              type="text"
              name="search"
              label={t("masterclass:search_label")}
              placeholder={t("masterclass:search_placeholder")}
              value={keyword}
              width={100}
              onChange={handleKeywordChange}
              optional={true}
            ></InputSingleLine>
          </form>

          {keywords.map((word, i) => {
            return (
              <form className={styles.keyword} key={i} onSubmit={handleDeleteKeyword}>
                <span>{word}</span>
                <button>X</button>
              </form>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        {/** ===> SEARCH BAR <===*/}

        {/** ===> SECTIONS && SEARCHED VIDEOS <===*/}
        {/** TODO: Controlar el renderizado teniendo en cuenta las secciones también
         *      --> if sections.length > 0 && searchedVideos.length === 0 ?????
         */}
        {searchedVideos.length === 0 ? (
          sections.map((section) => {
            return (
              <div key={section.name}>
                <VideoList
                  key={section.name}
                  title={capitalizeFirstLetter(section.name)}
                  videos={section.videos ?? []} // ==> section.videos ? section.videos : []
                  handleVideoClick={setSelectedVideo}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <div>
            {searchedVideos.map((video) => {
              return (
                <StandardThumbnail
                  key={video.id}
                  onClick={
                    video.id ? () => setSelectedVideo(video) : console.log
                  }
                  locked={false}
                  selected={false}
                  image={
                    "/assets/images/lol-logo.png"
                  } /* TODO - Cambiar rutas de imagenes */
                  //image={video.image}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
        {/** ===> SECTIONS && SEARCHED VIDEOS <===*/}
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Masterclass;
```

El método handleSearchSubmit recoge la información del input de búsqueda y almacena lo buscado en un array de keywords. Tengo un useEffect que se ejecuta cuando cambia este array de keywords, modificando el listado de vídeos buscados para su posterior renderizado.

El caso es que se renderiza el componente ANTES de que se actualize el listado de vídeos buscados, y no entiendo cuál es el fallo.

Comment: ¿Es realmente necesario usar 3 funciones `useEffect()` en este caso? ¿No podrías unificar algo de tu lógica para reducirlos?

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer una SPA, por eso dependiendo de las acciones del usuario traigo una información u otra y la renderizo, pero creo que lo mejor será separar la lógica por páginas distintas y sacar la información por la url, ya que no he conseguido hacer que funcione la actualización bien

Answer (score 0):

Si dices que se renderiza antes de que termine el useffect de keywords en función de lo que ves en la consola por el console.log, no es así. cuando quieras hacer eso, ponlo de esta manera `console.log([...keywords], [...searchedVideos])`. Dado que al modificar searchedvideos modifica el valor de esta variable en los dos `console.log()` da igual que uno estuviera antes que la función que setea el valor.
De esta manera si veras el valor real

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, el problema me viene en el renderizado condicional que tengo, que entra por searchedVideos.length === 0 cuando esta lista de vídeos tiene elementos, y lo que creo que ocurre es que se renderiza y entra por esa condición ANTES de que se produzca el cambio de estado

Comment: En teoría da igual que pase por la primera condición antes de que se produzca el cambio de estado. Al cambiar el estado, se re-renderiza el componente y tendría que pasar por la otra condición. Cerciórate de que la búsqueda de videos tenga resultados.... no vaya a ser.

Comment: Efectivamente las consultas se hacen bien y traen resultados, y los estados se actualizan correctamente, pero el renderizado no se produce como espero que sea… podría ser que react no detecte el cambio de estado y haya que forzarlo?